# Convert csv file to shapefile in R

Tags: shapefile, r, rgdal

Below is so far I've done to convert `.csv` file into shapefile

```
Mydata <- read.csv("londonburglary201402.csv", header = T, sep = ",")
class(Mydata)
coordinates(Mydata) <- ~Longitude + Latitude
class(Mydata)
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

but I don't know how to write the shapefile with projection.
I am trying to use rgdal packages to do.

Comment: Please edit into your question the output of `class(Mydata)`, also mention the projection your data uses, and the library you are using to create a shape file. Make sure to take the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) which will provide some guidelines for Q&A in GIS SE

Comment: I've edited now. Please let me know if the format now is okay. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest is probably with the raster package:

```
require(raster)
projection(Mydata) = "+init=espg:4326" # WGS84 coords
shapefile(Mydata, "Mydata.shp")
```

But with `sp` and `rgdal`:

```
proj4string(Mydata) = CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
writeOGR(Mydata, ".","Mydata", "ESRI Shapefile")
```

The "." is the current directory, and "Mydata" is the root name of the files that make up the shapefile.

Comment: How does your answer handle projection?

Comment: Does now. check edit.

Comment: Thank you @ Spacedman. However it doesn't solve my prob. Below is the error appear                                                                                       Warning message:
In .newCRS(value) : +init=espg:4326 is not a valid PROJ.4 CRS string

Comment: Why not? Why do you need to use rgdal? Okay, I'll add that solution too. But seriously, use the `raster` package it makes life easier.

Comment: Sorry. I am very new for R code. But I tried to use your code, it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Have you not installed the `raster` package? Do `install.packages("raster")` if the error is with `require(raster)`

Comment: Yes. I did do install.packages("raster") and library(raster) as well. Don't know why it doesn't work. Thank you so much for your help. The second sort out my prob.

Comment: You can also try the following: `proj4string(Mydata) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")`

Answer (score 0):

I think this converts a `CSV` file to a `shapefile` using the `sf` package:

```
setwd('C:/Users/mark_/Documents/ctmm/density_in_R')

library(sf)

# Create lat-long data
set.seed(1234)
# 21.4389° N, 158.0001° W
longitude <- rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1) + -158.0
latitude  <- rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1) +   21.4
timestamp <- as.POSIXct("2021-06-24 10:30:05", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")
my.data <- data.frame(longitude, latitude, timestamp)
head(my.data)
write.csv(my.data, "fake_lat_long_points_oahu.csv", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)

# fake lat-long data imported from CSV file
oahu.lat.long <- read.csv("fake_lat_long_points_oahu.csv", header = TRUE, 
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "NA")

head(oahu.lat.long)

# Code in the following section based on:
# https://www.gisnote.com/2020/11/23/csv-to-shapefile-in-r/
# https://erinbecker.github.io/r-raster-vector-geospatial/10-vector-csv-to-shapefile-in-r/index.html

# Define coordinate reference system
prj4string <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
my.projection <- st_crs(prj4string)

# Create sf object
oahu_lat_long_sf <- st_as_sf(oahu.lat.long, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = my.projection)
st_crs(oahu_lat_long_sf)

plot(oahu_lat_long_sf)

# Export shapefile
st_write(oahu_lat_long_sf, "C:/Users/mark_/Documents/ctmm/density_in_R/fake_oahu_lat_long_sf_June24_2021/oahu_lat_long_sf.shp", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Screenshot after importing `shapefile` into `QGIS` and adding a background map:

[image]